# How to implement many-to-many relationships for same entity in mapstruct?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapstruct

How to implement many-to-many relationships for same entity in mapstruct?

I have a problem. Example entity:
`class A { List<A> list = new ArrayList<>(); }`

How can i map recursive List in mapper?

How must to look class Mapper for A in Mapstruct?

Comment: For questions like this I would suggest to share how you would like to map this recursive list by hand and then go from there to define the MapStruct mapping.